# Go: Need to set property but without pointer receiver?

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyClass struct{
    data    string
}

func (this MyClass) MyMethod() {
    this.data = "Changed!"
}

func main() {
    obj := MyClass{}

    obj.MyMethod()

    fmt.Println(obj)
}
```

I need that the `data` property gets changed by `MyMethod()`, but I cannot change the receiver type to pointer (`func (this *MyClass)`) because it must satisfy an interface whose receiver is not a pointer, can this achieved some other way?

Comment: Interfaces don't specify what the receiver type must be.

Comment: And everything you are asking again was answered in your previous question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a pointer receiver, not a value receiver:

```
func (this *MyClass) MyMethod() {
    this.data = "Changed!"
}
```

See your modified example in [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/51W93Z7n0T):

The output is:

```
{Changed!}
```